# how to translate this query into Criteria?

Tags: symfony1, criteria, propel

I try to translate this query into Criteria (with Propel), but without success.

Can you help me please ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT (email)
FROM user, travail
WHERE travail.id_user = user.id_user
AND id_site = "1"
AND `droits` = "1"
```

This my Criteria query :

```
  $c = new Criteria();
  $c->add(self::DROITS, 1, Criteria::EQUAL);
  $c->add(TravailPeer::ID_SITE, 1, CRITERIA::EQUAL);
  $c->setDistinct(self::EMAIL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(UserPeer::DROITS, 1);
$c->addJoin(UserPeer::ID_USER, TravailPeer::ID_USER);
$c->add(TravailPeer::ID_SITE, 1);
$c->clearSelectColumns();
$c->addSelectColumn(UserPeer::EMAIL);
$c->setDistinct();

$rs = UserPeer::doSelectRS($c);
```

Comment: I obtain an error : Error populating User object [wrapped: Invalid resultset column: 2]

Comment: D'oh, last line should read: `$rs = UserPeer::doSelectRS($c);`

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use propel builder to translate not only this but any sql to the criteria. following is one of the online builder site.

http://propel.jondh.me.uk/